# LibreOffice SDK:How install and config LibreOffice SDK in mac

Tags: java, libreoffice

How can I install the libreoffice SDK in mac?
It always print"Error: Could not find directory '/usr/bin' or '/usr/bin/Commands/javac",

[image]
but i have installed java：
[image]

anyone can help,thanks~

Answer (score 0):

You installed the JRE (Java Runtime Environment), but you need JDK (Java Development Kit).

Comment: but have you installed it?

Comment: yes,i have insalled jdk7 and jdk8,I have tried the jdk7 home and jdk8 home,but it is not worked.