# Where should the LibreOffice SDK folder go after installation?

Tags: libreoffice

I downloaded the SDK because I was trying to use macros for LibreOffice Calc on a Mac. My macros are working, but I am not sure what to do with the SDK installation folder at this point. The SDK folder is currently in my Downloads folder. See the contents of the folder I am referring to below:

```
LibreOffice7.5_SDK
├── bin
├── classes
├── config.guess
├── config.sub
├── configure.pl
├── docs
├── examples
├── include
├── index.html
├── setsdkenv_unix
├── setsdkenv_unix.sh.in
├── settings
└── share
```

- Can it be moved elsewhere?
- Can it be deleted?
- Is there a place where it typically goes?

A related SO question, [LibreOffice SDK:How install and config LibreOffice SDK in mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467877/libreoffice-sdkhow-install-and-config-libreoffice-sdk-in-mac), is not helpful for this question because it is about an error in the installation process, not about what to do after installation.

As confirmation of a successful installation, my `$HOME` directory contains the `setsdkenv_unix` script. I am following installation directions on the [LibreOffice Installation Guide](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/install.html)

Comment: Just leave it there.  The `setsdvenv_unix` script will set up the environment variables that are needed for the compiler to find the include files it needs.

Comment: @TimRoberts I would like to move it out of the Downloads folder. Will it cause problems with the `setsdvenv_unix` script if I move it somewhere else?

Comment: Ah, yes.  I usually create a `src` folder to contain things like this.  I don't unpack the tarballs in the Downloads folder.  It will have to create a new `setsdkenv_unix` file.  It says it creates that file on first use, so perhaps you can just remove the file that's there.  Or, edit the file and replace "Downloads" with "src" or whatever you choose.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you. I think that will work. There is only one line in the `setsdkenv_unix.sh` file that references the folder location (where `OO_SDK_HOME` is defined), so only that line had to be changed. If you would post an answer with what you said in the comments I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually create a `src` folder to contain things like this. I don't unpack the tarballs in the Downloads folder. It will have to create a new `setsdkenv_unix` file. It says it creates that file on first use, so perhaps you can just remove the file that's there. Or, edit the file and replace "Downloads" with "src" or whatever you choose.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, it goes to the /opt/ folder.